# Could NOT find GMP

Tags: python, python3

I cannot install **mshr** and get the folllowing bug: How  can I install **mshr** in Ubuntu?

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
Could NOT find GMP (missing: GMP_LIBRARIES GMP_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
3rdparty/CGAL/cmake/modules/FindGMP.cmake:60 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
CMakeLists.txt:49 (find_package)
```

Best
Yaakov

Comment: Please add the results of `apt-cache policy libgmp-dev` to your question.

Comment: this method not working.....